# Why can't I use data from my Google spreadsheet when creating Jira issues using REST API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jira, jira-rest-api

**Summary**

I'm trying to write a script in Google Sheets that allows me to create issues in Jira Cloud using REST API whenever I edit a particular cell. In addition, the Jira issue should contain information that I pulled from my spreadsheet.

I managed to get the trigger to work and got a successful response from the Jira API. I can successfully create issues but only with issue field information that I put into the script. As soon as I try to use data from my spreadsheet, it doesn't work anymore.

I looked if there are any related questions on stackoverflow but couldn't find any that addressed this particular issue.

**Description**

An issue should be created as soon as I edit a specific cell in my spreadsheet and I'm using the `specialOnEdit()` function which allows me to target the cell that is currently located in the last row containing any values and column 6. My code looks like this

```
function specialOnEdit(evt) {
  var range = evt.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name of my sheet');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  if(range.getRow() == lastRow && range.getColumn() == 6) {
   createIssue()
  }
}
```

The `createIssue()` function contains my code for connecting to the Jira API. It looks like this

```
function createIssue() {
  
    var url = "https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue";
    var username = "xxxxx";
    var password = "xxxxx";
    var userCredentials = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);

    var data = {
      "fields": {
        "summary": "summary",
        "issuetype": {
          "id": "id",
        },
        "project": {
          "id": "id"
        },
        "priority": {
          "id": "id",
        }
      }
    };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

      var headers = { "Accept":"application/json",
                  "Content-Type":"application/json",
                  "Authorization": userCredentials,
                  "muteHttpExceptions": "True",
      };
      var options = { "method":"POST",
                    "headers": headers,
                    "payload": payload,
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

So far so good, everything works. If I edit the target cell, a Jira issue is being created containing the information I put into the respective `"fields":`.

Now I want to use cell values from my Google Sheet to populate those `"fields":`; the values being again from my last row that contains any values and this time column 1. However, if I start to declare variables for that in my `createIssue()` function the script doesn't work anymore. What I tried looks like this

```
function specialOnEdit(evt) {
  var range = evt.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('name of my sheet');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  if(range.getRow() == lastRow && range.getColumn() == 6) {
   createIssue()
  }
}

function createIssue() {

    var url = "https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue";
    var username = "xxxxx";
    var password = "xxxxx";
    var userCredentials = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName('name of my sheet');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var summary = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1);

    var data = {
      "fields": {
        "summary": summary,
        "issuetype": {
          "id": "id",
        },
        "project": {
          "id": "id"
        },
        "priority": {
          "id": "id",
        }
      }
    };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

      var headers = { "Accept":"application/json",
                  "Content-Type":"application/json",
                  "Authorization": userCredentials,
                  "muteHttpExceptions": "True",
      };
      var options = { "method":"POST",
                    "headers": headers,
                    "payload": payload,
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

If trigger the `specialOnEdit()` function, nothing happens but I don't get any error message in the console either. Does anyone know what seems to be the problem? Or is this simply not possible?

*edit
If I add a variable using a text string like so
`var summary = "example string"` it works just fine. As soon as I add any variables related to my spreadsheet the function doesn't work anymore regardless whether I fix the `getValue()` mistake as pointed out by Cooper.

In theory only adding something like

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet().getSheetByName('name of my sheet');
```

without anything else should not have any effect but it shouldn't mess with my function either which it does. Might be an important detail.

Answer (score -1):

`var summary = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1);`  should be `var summary = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();`

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Good point, I missed that one. It doesn't fix my problem though. I added `.getValue()` to my variable but to no effect.